# isNaN() function with multiple values in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can check more than one values in isNaN function in javascript?
like this,

```
if(isNaN(tesvalue1,testvalue2,testvalue3)) {    
  //alert( );
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the result be? `true/false` or the values which are `NaN`?

Comment: No. Seriously, how hard would it have been to check that?

Comment: P.S. Google is your friend. First result when you search for `isNaN`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: I'm voting unclear what you're asking now as the expected behavior is not defined and the two existing answers already implement opposite behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're here after:

If you want to test all of the value is NaN then use && operator:

```
if(isNaN(tesvalue1) && isNaN(testvalue2) && isNaN(testvalue3)) {    
  //alert( );
}
```

If you want to test any of the value is NaN then use || operator:

```
if(isNaN(tesvalue1) || isNaN(testvalue2) || isNaN(testvalue3)) {    
  //alert( );
}
```

Or, if you want to combine(add) all values and test if it is NaN:

```
if(isNaN(tesvalue1+testvalue2+testvalue3)) {    
  //alert( );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this function to test if some of values are NaN:

```
function testSomeNaN() {
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).some(isNaN);
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

To test if all values are NaN:

```
function testEveryNaN() {
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).every(isNaN);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

If your intention is to know which items in the arguments array are a number:

```
function filterNonNaN() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
       .filter(function(x){return !isNaN(x);});
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

If you have all data in array then use:

```
var arr = [1,2,NaN,3];
if(arr.some(isNaN)) {...} // some elements are NaN
// or
if([1,2,NaN,3].some(isNan)) {...}

if(arr.every(isNaN)) {...}// all elements are NaN
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(x){return !isNaN(x)}); // non-NaN elements
```

```js
function testSomeNaN() {
         return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).some(isNaN);
    }

function testEveryNaN() {
         return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).every(isNaN);
    }

   function filterNonNaN() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).filter(function(x){return !isNaN(x);});
}

document.getElementById("res11").textContent = testSomeNaN(1,2,NaN,4);
document.getElementById("res12").textContent = testSomeNaN(1,2,3,4);
document.getElementById("res13").textContent = testSomeNaN(NaN,NaN);

document.getElementById("res21").textContent = testEveryNaN(1,2,NaN,4);
document.getElementById("res22").textContent = testEveryNaN(1,2,3,4);
document.getElementById("res23").textContent = testEveryNaN(NaN,NaN);

document.getElementById("res31").textContent = filterNonNaN(1,2,NaN,4);
```

```html
<p>Some NaN:</p>
<p>1,2,NaN,4: <span id="res11"></span></p>
<p>1,2,3,4: <span id="res12"></span></p>
<p>NaN,NaN: <span id="res13"></span></p>

<p>Every NaN:</p>
<p>1,2,NaN,4: <span id="res21"></span></p>
<p>1,2,3,4: <span id="res22"></span></p>
<p>NaN,NaN: <span id="res23"></span></p>

<p>Filter Non NaN:</p>
<p>1,2,NaN,4: <span id="res31"></span></p>
```

Comment: It's completely unclear whether this is even the expected behavior by the OP.

Comment: Slicing `arguments` [can have negative performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509312/does-node-js-really-not-optimize-calls-to-slice-callarguments).

Comment: I think `filter()` would be more appropriate because `some()` returns immediately as soon as an item satisfies the criteria.

Comment: 1. some() function is faster then filter() 2. In case if you need to test all values, use every(isNaN) instead some(isNaN)

Comment: The OP's intention is to know which items in the arguments array are a number, so `filter()` is more appropriate IMO

Comment: Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).filter(function(x){return !isNaN(x);})

Comment: I added this option to the answer. Thanks!